# C# - How to add next line text from textbox to new column in gridview?

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to add the next line text in a textbox to a new line in gridview.

This is my current code:

```
<Label x:Name="label1" Content="URL :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="22,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
<TextBox x:Name="textBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="146" Margin="64,30,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Enter URLs Here" GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="555" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
<Button x:Name="button1" Content="Check &amp; Index" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="652,19,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="134" Height="40" Click="Button1_Click"/>
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,0.333">
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="459" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1700" Margin="22,185,0,-121.666" AutoGenerateColumns="True" SelectionChanged="dataGrid_SelectionChanged">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="URL" Width="150" Binding="{Binding URL}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Code Behind:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGrid1.Items.Add(new { URL = textBox1.Text});
    }
```

Current code just inserts all text from textBox1 into 1 single column. What I want is let's say I have 5 lines in textBox1, each line should be added into new row.

Comment: `textBox1.Text.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList().ForEach(line => dataGrid.Items.Add(line));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2) the lines of the textbox1.

```
List<string> Urllines = theText.Split(
                                    new[] { Environment.NewLine }, 
                                    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
                                    ).ToList();
```

and then

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach(string strUrl in Urllines)
        dataGrid1.Items.Add(new { URL = strUrl});
}
```

We use `RemoveEntryEmpties` as the second parameter to avoid empty results.

Comment: you beat me to it. :)